# Why does my MongoClient connect to different port than asked?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem about mongo client connecting to a different port than told. So basically, I have 2 mongodb servers on the same host, one on 27017 and another on 27018. I want the mongo client to connect to 27018, but it connects to 27017. This is connection url / code:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(`mongodb://host:27018`);
```

I am using 5.5.0 version of the "mongodb" package and 14.17.0 of node.js. If connecting to these servers through NoSQLBooster, everything works fine. When using 3.7.3 version of the "mongodb" package, it works fine, but with a message about deprecation.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Why do you think it connects to port 27017 when connection string is `mongodb://host:27018`?

Comment: My program is intended to insert records into a specific database. I am using NoSQLBooster to look at databases, tables, etc. and when I insert a record, it is inserted in a specific database on host:27017. If I change the URI to host:27017, it inserts into host:27017 too.

Comment: "So basically, I have 2 databases on the same host, one on 27017 and another on 27018" - you mean 2 mongodb servers?

Comment: Yes, sorry. 2 mongodb servers

Comment: Stop 27017 server and try to connect to 27018 server like in your sample.

Comment: Stupid question, why do you have 2 instances? Apart from developing, testing, etc. I cannot imaging any valid reason.

Comment: @mtkachenko stopped 27017 and it still connects to 27017, even if the port is set to 27018. MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED host:27017

const mongoClient = new MongoClient(`mongodb://${MONGODB_HOST}:${MONGODB_PORT}`);
where MONGODB_HOST = host, MONGODB_PORT = 27018

Comment: You're doing something wrong here. If mongoserver  is stopped it should be impossible to connect to it because - you know - there is no process listening on 27017